# W3C validation of Joomla page: "The type attribute is unnecessary for JavaScript resources."

Tags: javascript, html, joomla, w3c-validation

From the beginning of this month, W3C XHTML started to point out this error:

> The `type` attribute is unnecessary for JavaScript resources.

I do not use `type` anymore in my JavaScript but this above error is generated inside Joomla script itself to call modules or jQuery, CSS, etc. and is not written in any Joomla file. Probably is related the way Joomla call scripts in core files.

So I need help. I am in version 3.8.3 and error still there.

Comment: I don't know about `Joomla` that much but you wrap the script inside `CDATA`, it starts with  `<![CDATA[` and ends with`]]>`.The term CDATA is used about text data that should not be parsed by the XML parser.Everything inside a CDATA section is ignored by the parser.

Comment: I would ask on the joomla stackexchange site [joomla.se]. If you aren't seeing a lot of complaints when searching in Google it is possibly from a add on module or plugin.  When asking a question you should always explain what research you have done.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic for SO because it definitely is off topic but it could go to joomla.se.

Comment: I removed all the modules, the warnings decrease, but they continue. I tested with another template and no solution. I do not understand how changing the CDATA XML can help. This problem also appears in Wordpress, but a workaround was found: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/287830/remove-type-attribute-from-script-and-style-tags-added-by-wordpress. In Joomla I did not find any solution. I will post this problem on the joomla stackexchange site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the correct joomla output to HTML5.
Write in your Template index (above where is the PHP code portion):

```
// Set HTML5 Document Output
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->setHtml5(true);
```

All "Type" declarations through Joomla HEAD Renderer must disappear.

Comment: I put the code you mentioned at the beginning of index.php and it worked perfectly! There were a few more warnings that were in the linkbuilder.php file because I used JCH Optimize, but it was easily fixed by removing the "type" in the file itself. Thank you for your solution!